# Converting String of 1's and 0's to a binary file

Tags: java, string, binary

So I have a String of thousands of 1's and 0's that I want to save to a file as binary (so that file size is small). Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to do it without running into NumberFormatExceptions.

I've tried Byte.parseByte but that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 try {
        File file = new File(BINARY_FILE);
        DataOutputStream dso = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        for (int j = 0; j < bits.length(); j += 8) {
            Byte b = Byte.parseByte(bits.substring(j, j + 8));
            dso.write(b);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

Comment: show the code that you have tried

Comment: Added, the bits variable is the string of 1's and 0's.

Comment: Also, are we guaranteed that the length of the String will be divisible by 8?

Comment: No, we are not, which does cause a problem with dealing with the last characters in the string. Which is why I would prefer there be a way to write out individual bits.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is write bytes, don't wrap with [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).

You should also use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to close the file stream when done.

When parsing the 8 bits, you need to specify radix 2, otherwise you're parsing base-10 numbers, not binary.

Parsing is for signed numbers, so since you're using 8-bit unsigned byte, you should parse to `int`, instead of `byte`.<sup>1</sup>

You shouldn't use [`valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-int-), but instead use [`parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-). No need to get boxed object.

So, you code should be:

```
try {
    File file = new File(BINARY_FILE);
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bits.length(); j += 8) {
            int b = Integer.parseInt(bits.substring(j, j + 8), 2);
            out.write(b);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

<sup>1</sup> `parseByte(s, 2)` is a signed parse, so it onlu supports values between `"-10000000"` (-128<sub>10</sub>) and `"01111111"` (127<sub>10</sub>). Any 8-digit binary number starting with `1` will fail with `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"11111111" Radix:2`

Comment: Seems a bit inefficient to use a 32 bit int when a 8 bit byte would do, though, just because of the sign.

Comment: @DM The [`write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write-int-) takes an `int` as parameter, even though it only uses the lower 8 bits, so it'll be converted to `int` anyway, whether you parse to `byte`, `short`, or `int`. Can't parse to byte without error, so might as well parse to `int`, since that's what method wants.

Comment: This seemed work but will continue to try and improve if there is something better.

Comment: @Andreas Oh, wow, I didn't realize `write` ignored most of the passed-in integer.  I thought that was what `writeByte` was for.  That's what I get for assuming.

Comment: @DM Yup. Don't assume. Read the javadoc. :-)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the radix of 2, though?

Comment: Also, how does this differentiate between a String of "00001111" and a String of "1111" ?

Comment: @DM You can't. It's the same byte value.

Comment: @DM Oops, forgot the dang `, 2`. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to address the one thing that hasn't been yet: how to handle odd bits.

You cannot write individual bits to a file, only bytes.  File sizes are always full bytes, and even if Java could handle files with a file size of a fraction of a byte, your filesystem couldn't.

In order to output those last few digits that may or may not be a full 8, you can do something like this:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < bits.length(); j += 8) {
        int b;
        if (j + 8 < bits.length())
        {
            b = Integer.parseInt(bits.substring(j, j + 8), 2);
        }
        else
        {
            b = Integer.parseInt(bits.substring(j), 2);
        }
        dso.write(b);
    }
```

Now your `substring` won't go off the end of the String.

As far as how to differentiate between a String ending in "00001111" vs a String ending in "1111" (which have the same byte value), perhaps you could write, at the beginning of the file, a byte with the value `bits.length % 8`.  This will let you know how to handle that last byte.  If it's 6, for example, then you know that 1111 is really "001111" and not "1111".  If it's 4, then it really was "1111".